# Using writerow with numbers

Tags: python, csv

The function i am working on, should add a new row  of strings and numbers delimited each time it is called.
I am passing a string and a list of numbers as the arguments to the function.
Currently, it only writes the argument as follows, when function called:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

However, I want the function to write the code as delimited as given below:

```
1.0     2.0     3.0
```

It looks like, I didn't comprehend writerow functions very well. So my question is, how can I delimit a list of numbers that is passed to writerow?

```
    # writes the results to a csv file
    # each row contains a string and three numbers
    def write_to_file(file_name, n_t_argument):
        with open(file_name + '.txt', 'a', newline='') as outputfile:
            wrtr  = csv.writer(outputfile, dialect = 'excel-tab')
            text_input = [ n_t_argument ]
            wrtr.writerow(text_input)

    write_to_file('output', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your numbers in a *nested* list, a list in a list. No need to do that:

```
def write_to_file(file_name, n_t_argument):
    with open(file_name + '.txt', 'a', newline='') as outputfile:
        wrtr  = csv.writer(outputfile, dialect = 'excel-tab')
        wrtr.writerow(n_t_argument)
```

Comment: because the real answer is deleted, i will paste Martijn's response to here: We need to pass a flat list rather than list of lists to make writerow work as intended as asked in the question.